# javascript api call too many request

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am making an API call to imagify to create compressed images of different sizes. The sizes are coming from an array of sizes i get from a wordpress domain when this code is run it generates too many request. The test array i am using should only generate two calls to generate two different sizes for the same image.

> result :{"code":422,"detail":"Too many request, be patient","success":false}
>   result :{"code":422,"detail":"Too many request, be patient","success":false}
>   result :{"code":422,"detail":"Too many request, be patient","success":false}
>   result :{"code":422,"detail":"Too many request, be patient","success":false}
>   result :{"code":422,"detail":"Too many request, be patient","success":false}
>   result :{"code":422,"detail":"Too many request, be patient","success":false}
>   result :{"code":422,"detail":"Too many request, be patient","success":false}
>   result :{"code":422,"detail":"Too many request, be patient","success":false}

```
var sizes = '{thumbnail: {width: 500, height:500,crop:true}, medium: {width: 500, height:500,crop:true}';

send_to_imagify("test", "test", sizes, token);

function send_to_imagify(title, image, sizes, token) {

    var nodeImagifyAPI = require("node-imagify-api");

    for (var i in sizes) {
        var options = {
            'ultra': true,
            'resize': {
                'width': sizes[i].width,
                'height': sizes[i].height
            }
        };

        var apiCallback = function(result) {
            console.log("result :" + JSON.stringify(result));
        }

        nodeImagifyAPI.uploadImage(token, options, "test_image.jpg", apiCallback);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check out the server logs to make sure that this is causing the trouble.

Comment: There isn't enough information off this code, can you either add more code or better explain how this code is run.

Comment: @zlwaterfield I disagree. OP, `sizes` is a **string**. The line `for (var i in sizes)` is going to iterate through **every single character of the string**.

Comment: The only other code is the token key and i dont want to make that public

Comment: @Santi you are correct, good catch.

Comment: I think Santi is correct thank you I missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizes` is a string, so your `for` loop is acting on each individual character:

```js
var sizes = '{thumbnail: {width: 500, height:500,crop:true}, medium: {width: 500, height:500,crop:true}';

send_to_imagify("test", "test", sizes, "");

function send_to_imagify(title, image, sizes, token) {
  // ...
  for (var i in sizes) {
    console.log(i, sizes[i])
  }
}
```

Take those single quotes off the definition of `sizes`, add the missing closing `}`, and you should be good to go:

```
var sizes = {thumbnail: {width: 500, height:500,crop:true}, medium: {width: 500, height:500,crop:true}};
```